# Automating screenshots using pyscreenshot

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to automate screenshots after a click on Windows .. so grab initial screenshot; click and then take another screenshot click and so on .. and do this for a specified amount of times.

I am able to generate the list of image files but the 'im' variable is not updating .. it saves the same image as image_1 onto image_2. Any idea what am I doing wrong here?

```
import pyscreenshot as imageGrab
import pyautogui
i=1
for i in range(1,3):

        im = imageGrab.grab(bbox=(0,170,2179,787))
        im.save('image_'+str(i)+'jpg','JPEG')
        pyautogui.click(2321,133,duration=3) # Next image
        i=i+1
```

Comment: Fascinating. This code crashes hard when run from PyCharm on a Mac. When run from the console it does not save even 1 image for me. As far as I know this only works on Windows. if this is the case perhaps mention this in your post.

Comment: Thx. I updated it.